# Must I import Foundation when making a struct dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary, struct

I have made a simple Swift file that constains some data like bellow:

```
import Foundation    

struct someData {
    let stringsAsInts: [name: String, value: Int] = [
        "zero" : 0,
        "one" : 1,
        "two" : 2,
        "three" : 3,
        "four" : 4,
        "five" : 5,
        "six" : 6,
        "seven" : 7,
        "eight" : 8,
        "nine" : 9
    ]
}
```

I then fetch that data in my VC by calling

```
let somedata = someData()
```

But must I include `import Foundation` in the file containing the struct? It works without it when I test at least.

Comment: Why would you need it? If it works without it, why are you asking?

Comment: Because when I create a new empty file xcode import it by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need Foundation imported if you want to use its features. One such feature would be the various `NSString` methods, like `componentsSeparatedByString(_:)`. A Swift `String` is not bridged to `NSString` without importing Foundation: `NSString` doesn't even exist as far as that code is concerned, and so neither do those methods.

Another example is to be able to refer to bridged types, like `String` <=> `NSString` or `Array` <=> `NSArray`, using `AnyObject`, for example when processing results from a Parse backend. Without Foundation imported, and the associated bridging, `String` and `Array` are instances of `struct`s, not of `class`es.

If you're using only native Swift types and don't need to call Foundation-only methods on them, you don't need to import the Foundation module.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Xcode imported it by default when I created a new file and that got me thinking. But I only use the dict to populate a uipickerView so I will delete it then